# Variable/Code to use in template so content of the page shows at the spot

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Learning some wordpress, creating my first custom wordpress site. I created template for my home page and then I want to create one template for a good bunch of sub pages. So I created a file page-sub.php. In pages I can see this template, so I assigned it to my sub pages. But I'm missing the code/variable to show the content of the page that uses the template. Can you guys advise what do I need? Below is my code in the template so far.

```
<?php
 /*
   Template Name: Sub Page Template
 */

  get_header();
?>

<div class="main">
  <div class="container">

     <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        endif;

        the_content();
     ?>

   </div>
</div>
<?php 
    get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: `the_content();`  is used to display content section. What can you see on that page actually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the Wordpress Post loop.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} ?>
```

Perhaps this is what you're looking for.
https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

As far as your code goes I might try to make you html outside the php 
for example to do what I think you want to do is this.

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    } 
} ?>
```

I am not 100% on why you are using the singular if statement. Is there something specific you want to do with that?
Something like this?

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
            if ( is_singular() ) : 
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); 
            endif; 
            the_content(); 
        } 
    }
?>
```

Comment: `the_content();` has nothing to do with loop actually

Comment: That is true. But the above is a common use for a template. Maybe they should try turning on the Debugging. Perhaps he has something wrong in the header or footer. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: First of all we should know, how that page look like and what it is displaying currently. So that we can identify, where the code is getting breaked

Comment: @SudharshanNair You see in the template a header and a footer, both of them show so the template part is fine. When I set this template for a page and add content, that content does not show and this is why im asking for the code/variable I should be using.

Comment: @itivae I tried to give your code a try but I'm getting an unexpected end of file error. Sorry still finding my ways around php and wordpress. I'm sure its a minor fix.

Comment: @itivae so what finally worked is:
 <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post(); 
                        if ( is_singular() ) :
                            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                        endif;

                        the_content();
                    }
                }
 ?>

Comment: @itivae Please modify your answer with html outside of php so it does not throw an  error and I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: @sayayin I have edited my code to reflect what worked for you.